# All pages redirect to home page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Hi I am having a funny issue with Wordpress runnign on XAMPP. Mysteriously all of my pages including my admin page are redirecting to my home page which is hosted on:

`http://localhost/client_projects/Active/example-site.co.uk`

This is what my .htaccess file looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /http://localhost/client_projects/Active/example-site.co.uk/index.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . http://localhost/client_projects/Active/example-site.co.uk [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have also made sure that in phpmyadmin my table `wp_options` that siteurl and home fields are both pointing to `http://localhost/client_projects/Active/example-site.co.uk`

I unfortunately can not access my admin panel.

Why is my wordpress doing this?

**EDIT:**

On updating my .htaccess file to the following, all of my pages get redirected to `localhost/dashboard`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have been working with Laravel and added the following to my `https-vhosts.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/php/frameworks/laravel/lsapp/public"
    ServerName lsapp.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

And my windows32/drivers hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost 
127.0.0.1 lsapp.dev
```

I am not sure if this is affecting anything, I have tried to revert the changes and it doesn't affect anything.

Comment: Well, that last rule you show in your rewriting set _excplicitly_ rewrites every request to the base URL.

Comment: And, btw: a rewrite base cannot be a URL... especially not a "URL with a slash in front of it"...

Comment: Right, I am confused here, is there a correct .htaccess file that I can compare against?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have WP installed in `C:/xampp/htdocs/client_projects/Active/example-site.co.uk/` than change the RewriteBase accordingly:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /client_projects/Active/example-site.co.uk/
    RewriteRule index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The reason why all your request going to the main page it the following:
`RewriteRule . http://localhost/client_projects/Active/example-site.co.uk [L]`

Comment: Great, the problem was the slash in `RewriteRule . \index.php [L]`, `RewriteRule . index.php [L]` fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, with the slash RewriteBase is useless in this case. Alternativ you could do  `RewriteRule . /client_projects/Active/example-site.co.uk/index.php [L]`

Answer (score 1):

The last line of your .htaccess

```
RewriteRule . http://localhost/client_projects/Active/example-site.co.uk [L]
```

Explicitely reroutes to your home page.

Should be something like

```
  # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /client_projects/Active/example-site.co.uk/
    RewriteRule index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Right thank you Benoit, unfortunately now when I try to go to a page on my site it redirects to `localhost/dashboard`

Comment: Yes, sorry, amended my answer.

Comment: Nice that you copy my Solution

Comment: Didn't mean to copy anything. I amended my answer and then saw yours that was identical. I even upvoted yours. Sorry if you got this feeling

Answer (score 1):

Can you try please first take backup of your .htaccess file. Then delete this .htaccess file. After then try to access your admin side. But before that please also clear your browser data. After login admin side save parsmlinks so it will generate new htaccess file. Please refer this link : http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-login-page-refreshing-and-redirecting-issue/